# Comparison between one observation and the others by level of a factor

Tags: r, comparison

Sorry about the vague title, but I cannot figure out how this operation is supposed to be called. I guess it could be a leave-one-out process, but I'll explain. I have this:

```
structure(list(Ident = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A_1_2", "A_1_4"), class = "factor"), 
    iduni = c("A_1_2_231", "A_1_2_233", "A_1_2_234", "A_1_2_235", 
    "A_1_2_236", "A_1_2_237", "A_1_4_200", "A_1_4_201", "A_1_4_202", 
    "A_1_4_203", "A_1_4_204", "A_1_4_205", "A_1_4_206"), Dhp = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 13L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("92", 
    "100", "102", "118", "126", "139", "155", "176", "196", "220", 
    "234", "241", "263"), class = "factor"), ratio = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Ident", 
"iduni", "score", "ratio"), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which basically is this small df:

```
   Ident     iduni score ratio
1  A_1_2 A_1_2_231  92    NA
3  A_1_2 A_1_2_233 102    NA
4  A_1_2 A_1_2_234 263    NA
5  A_1_2 A_1_2_235 155    NA
6  A_1_2 A_1_2_236 234    NA
7  A_1_2 A_1_2_237 241    NA
70 A_1_4 A_1_4_200 176    NA
71 A_1_4 A_1_4_201 196    NA
72 A_1_4 A_1_4_202 220    NA
73 A_1_4 A_1_4_203 100    NA
74 A_1_4 A_1_4_204 139    NA
75 A_1_4 A_1_4_205 118    NA
76 A_1_4 A_1_4_206 126    NA
```

And I would like to be able to select one observation for a specific level of "Ident" and compare its score to every other one within the level. For example, I'd like to obtain the sum of the ratio between one score and all the others for the level of Ident:

> ratio for i = Σ[ SCORE(line i)/SCORE(lines 1:i-1,i+1:n)]

Or even for example something simpler like:

> comparison for i = Σ[SCORE(lines 1:i-1,i+1:n)]

Ideally I would have to be able to set conditions on the selection of the other observations (for example only for scores superior to score i).

Thanks in advance for your help, and sorry about the awkward way the question is formulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data.table.

```
library(data.table)    
df$score=as.numeric(as.character(df$score))
df <- as.data.table(df)[, ratio1:=score/(sum(score)-score) , by = Ident]
df
    Ident     iduni score ratio     ratio1
 1: A_1_2 A_1_2_231    92    NA 0.09246231
 2: A_1_2 A_1_2_233   102    NA 0.10355330
 3: A_1_2 A_1_2_234   263    NA 0.31917476
 4: A_1_2 A_1_2_235   155    NA 0.16630901
 5: A_1_2 A_1_2_236   234    NA 0.27432591
 6: A_1_2 A_1_2_237   241    NA 0.28486998
 7: A_1_4 A_1_4_200   176    NA 0.19577308
 8: A_1_4 A_1_4_201   196    NA 0.22298066
 9: A_1_4 A_1_4_202   220    NA 0.25730994
10: A_1_4 A_1_4_203   100    NA 0.10256410
11: A_1_4 A_1_4_204   139    NA 0.14850427
12: A_1_4 A_1_4_205   118    NA 0.12330199
13: A_1_4 A_1_4_206   126    NA 0.13277134
```

Answer (score 0):

If you name your data.frame `df` then this is what you want:

```
df$ratios = ave(df$score,# the variable to summarize
       df$Ident,# the grouping variable(s)
       FUN=function(x)# the function that performs calculations on `df$score` within each grouping.
           # score ratio = this score / (sum of all scores but this one)
           x / (sum(x) - x)
        )


df$comparison_values = ave(df$score,# the variable to summarize
       df$Ident,# the grouping variable(s)
       FUN=function(x)# the function that performs calculations on `df$score` within each grouping.
           # comparison for I = (sum of all scores but this one)
           (sum(x) - x)
        )
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to take into account the grouping requested.

Answer (score 0):

So let's get ratio of each score to the mean of scores in positions above item # 3 within specific values of Ident-column. Could use other criteria but you were not entirely clear on this point.

```
#First need to convert the factor to a numeric.
dat$score <- as.numeric(as.character(dat$score))
i=3 # Pick a location 
dat$rat_scr <- ave( dat$score, dat$Ident, FUN=function(x){
                                   x/mean(x[(1+i):length(x) ]) })
 dat
   Ident     iduni score ratio   rat_scr
1  A_1_2 A_1_2_231    92    NA 0.4380952
3  A_1_2 A_1_2_233   102    NA 0.4857143
4  A_1_2 A_1_2_234   263    NA 1.2523810
5  A_1_2 A_1_2_235   155    NA 0.7380952
6  A_1_2 A_1_2_236   234    NA 1.1142857
7  A_1_2 A_1_2_237   241    NA 1.1476190
70 A_1_4 A_1_4_200   176    NA 1.4575569
71 A_1_4 A_1_4_201   196    NA 1.6231884
72 A_1_4 A_1_4_202   220    NA 1.8219462
73 A_1_4 A_1_4_203   100    NA 0.8281573
74 A_1_4 A_1_4_204   139    NA 1.1511387
75 A_1_4 A_1_4_205   118    NA 0.9772257
76 A_1_4 A_1_4_206   126    NA 1.0434783
```